# asp net mvc3 post a list of objects to action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a page with aspnet mvc3. It show all users info as a list. I want to do something with this list. There are some checkboxes that belong to each items. When I click some checkboxes and press submit button, I want to post the whole list as a collection and save each items of this collection to database. There are several notes on internet but there is no exact solution. I have a UserDto. and want to use this to transfer users data in all sections.

Does anyone have any full solution about this or can they give any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Kerem

Comment: do you have any code for what you have tried and what isn't working?  Have you created a model for your view's data and then tried handling data changes on the postback?  I'd recommend you review http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

Answer (score 0):

I added some of my codes. You can see the lead sentences what they are about.

this is my index view detail:

```
@model List<DomainModel.UserApprovalDto>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Users";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Manage Users</h2>
<div>@Html.Partial("_PartialManageUsers", (List<DomainModel.UserApprovalDto>)Model)        </div>
```

this is my partial view detail:

```
    @model  List<DomainModel.UserApprovalDto>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmUsers", "ManageUsers", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        Name
        </th>
        <th>
        Is Reported
        </th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("IsReported", Model[i].IsReported.HasValue ? Model[i].IsReported.Value : false)
            @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsReported.Value);*@ @*    @if (Model[i].IsReported != null)
            {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsReported.Value);
            }
            else
            {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsReported.Value);
            }*@
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <div>
    <input name="submitUsers" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

this is my controller submit method

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfirmUsers(List<DomainModel.UserApprovalDto> collection)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
    //TO-DO
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

this last one is my DTO class detail:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DomainModel
{
    public class UserApprovalDto
    {
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public Guid CarUserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public string PhotoSmallPath { get; set; }
    public string PhotoSquarePath { get; set; }
    public string PhotoBigPath { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    }
}
```

when I submit this code my list return null collection to my controller method.

thanks for your comments.

Comment: If you have additional information to add to your question, you should use the "edit" link under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating a screen which adds/ remove users to a course. So let's create some viewmodels

```
public class CourseVM
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int CourseID { set;get;}
  public List<UserVM> Users { set;get;}
  public CourseVM()
  {
    Users=new List<UserVM>();
  }
}
public class UserVM
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int UserID{ set;get;}
  public bool IsSelected { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your `GET` Action, you will fill the values of the ViewModel and sent it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var vm = new CourseVM();

    //The below code is hardcoded for demo. you may replace with DB data.
    vm.Users.Add(new UseVM { Name = "Jon" , UserID=1});
    vm.Users.Add(new UseVM { Name = "Scott", UserID=2 });

    return View(vm);
}
```

Now Let's create an EditorTemplate. Go to `Views/YourControllerName` and Crete a Folder called "**EditorTemplates**" and Create a new View there with the same name as of the Property Name(`UserVM.cshtml`)

Add this code to your new editor template.

@model ChannelViewModel

```
<p>
  <b>@Model.Name</b>   :
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected) <br />
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
</p>
```

Now in your Main View, Call your Editor template using the `EditorFor` Html Helper method.

```
@model CourseVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <div>  
      @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Users)         
    </div>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Now when you post the form, Your Model will have the `Users` Collection where the Selected Checkboxes will be having a `True` value for the `IsSelected` Property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(CourseVM model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Check for model.Users collection and Each items
      //  IsSelected property value.
      //Save and Redirect(PRG pattern)
   }
   return View(model);
}
```